# Modifying toc & bib titles

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

I would like to `\flushright` the toc's and bibliography's title, but the font size and spaces above and below should be the same as for regular chapters.

Here is what I did:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}{}

\begin{document}

{\titleformat{\chapter}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\flushright}{}\tableofcontents}
\chapter{First line of title\\second line of title}

\end{document}
```

There are two issues I cannot solve:

1. The toc's title is aligned with the second line of the chapter's title, and I would like it to be so with the first
2. A minor issue, but when calling the scope limited `\titleformat` I have to redefine the title's format, can that be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand what you mean with point 1. However, `\flushright` is wrong:

```
{\titleformat{\chapter}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\raggedleft}{}\tableofcontents}
```

won't add vertical space.

You can redefine `\tableofcontents`:

```
\let\origtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup 
  \titleformat{\chapter}
              {\Large\bfseries}
              {}
              {0pt}
              {\raggedleft}
              {}%
  \origtableofcontents
  \endgroup}
```

so that issuing `\tableofcontents` will be enough.

Comment: `\raggedleft` does the trick. What I meant was that the space below the toc's title was the same as the space below the second line of the title and consequently the space above 'Contents' was large than the space above the chapter's title's first line.